# Habilitar Botão em WPF C# através de uma função

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Tenho um formulário para preenchimento de alguns dados através de `Textbox`.

Tenho uma classe quem tem algumas funções de validação de campos nome, senha, usuário por exemplo. E em meu `Code Behind` apenas chamo a função que valida passando os parâmetros para ela. Se cada campo digitado for válido uma `string` declarada recebe o valor de *ok*.

Gostaria que no final após todos os campos serem validados o botão salvar que está desabilitado ficasse habilitado.

Vejam como estou fazendo:

```
string validacaoImg = "";
private void txt_nome(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string regex = "^[A-Za-záéíóúàâêôãõüçÁÉÍÓÚÀÂÊÔÃÕÜÇ ]+$";
    Funcao.validaCampos(regex, txtNome.Text, imgNome, validacaoImg);
}

private void txt_dtNascimento(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string regex = @"\d{2,2}/\d{2,2}/\d{4,4}";
    Funcao.validaCampos(regex, txtNascimento.Text, imgNascimento, validacaoImg);
}

private void txt_usuario(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string regex = "^[-@.A-Za-z0-9]+$";
    Funcao.validaCampos(regex, txtUsuario.Text, imgUsuario, validacaoImg);
}

private void txt_senha(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string regex = @"(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9].+$";
    Funcao.validaCampos(regex, txtSenha.Text, imgSenha, validacaoImg);
}
```

Minha classe `Função`:

```
public static void validaCampos(string regex, string txt, Image img, string validacaoImg)
{
    TextBox texto = new TextBox();
    texto.Text = txt;
    img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Regex rx = new Regex(regex);
    if (texto.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        if (validaTextBoxes(txt, rx))
        {                        
            texto.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
            validacaoImg = "check";
            texto.ToolTip = null;
        }
        else
        {
            texto.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;                    
            texto.ToolTip = "Fora do padrão!";
            validacaoImg = "errado";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        texto.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
        texto.ToolTip = "Este campo não pode ficar vazio!";
        validacaoImg = "errado";                
    }
    validarImagem(img, validacaoImg);
}

public static bool validaTextBoxes(string texto, Regex regex)
{
    bool isValid = regex.IsMatch(texto);

    if (isValid)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void validarImagem(Image img, string validacaoImg)
{
    var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Imagens/");
    var uri = new Uri(path + validacaoImg + ".jpg");
    BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(uri);
    img.Source = bm;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O primeiro bloco de código é chamado quando? No `Leave`?

Comment: @JéfersonBueno você se refere a qual bloco o da Classe que criei Funcao ou o que fica no CodeBehind do XAML?

Comment: Me refiro as funções `txt_nome`, `txt_dtNascimento` e as subsequentes.

Comment: @JéfersonBueno sim

Answer (score 0):

Adicione os Controles dentro de System.Windows.Controls.ValidationError, e a cada validação vai retirando(de valido), ou mantendo(não valido) e verificando nos Post's. a Collection Chegando a zero vc Habilita o salvar.